# Create urdf file "check_urdf" cannot check the urdf file

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i key in check_urdf mybot.urdf, the terminal shows the message like that :

```
Error:   Error reading end tag.
 at line 72 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

my system is Ubuntu 16.04, ROS version is kinetic

**mybot.urdf**

```
<robot name="turtlebot_nano">
    <link name="base_link" />
    <link name="right_back_wheel_link" />
    <link name="left_back_wheel_link" />
    <link name="right_front_wheel_link" />
    <link name="left_front_wheel_link" />
    <link name="lidar_link" />
    <link name="camera_link" />
    
    
    <joint name="joint1" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_back_wheel_link">
    </joint>
        
    <joint name="joint2" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_back_wheel_link"/>
    </joint>
        
    <joint name="joint3" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_front_wheel_link"/>
    </joint>
        
    <joint name="joint4" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_front_wheel_link"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="joint5" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="lidar_link"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="joint6" type="continuous">
        </parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link">
    </joint>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338818/create-urdf-file-%22check_urdf%22-cannot-check-the-urdf-file/) by [dhaour9x](https://answers.ros.org/users/49863/dhaour9x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It actually has checked your urdf in a way:

> ```
> Error:   Error reading end tag.
> ```

the error message is a bit terse, but we see this in your `joint6`:

> ```
> <joint name="joint6" type="continuous">
> ```

```
    </parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_link">
</joint>
```

Note `</parent link="base_link"/>` and `<child link="camera_link">`.

The first starts with `</` which is invalid, and the second ends with `>` but has no child elements, nor a closing `</child>`.

This is not valid XML, hence the error message.

---

Edit: `joint1` also has a problem:

> ```
> <child link="right_back_wheel_link">
> ```

again no closing element.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dhaour9x](https://answers.ros.org/users/49863/dhaour9x/) on 2019-11-28**:
I checked often, thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-28**:
I'm not sure I understand.

Have you been able to correct the mistakes and make `check_urdf` run correctly now?

**Comment by [dhaour9x](https://answers.ros.org/users/49863/dhaour9x/) on 2019-11-28**:
it works, thank yo